# Change fullName to firstName, lastName in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image]

We've updated our **User** collection to have `firstName`, `lastName` as 2 keys instead of `fullName`, but we have over 400 users that are currently created as `fullName`. I can use the MongoDB Atlas UI to manually create 400 sets of `firstName`, `lastName` keys, but that will take forever.

Can I use the mongo shell to (a) split the `fullName` by space, and (b) set the first name to the first value in the split array (everything before 1st space), and (c) set the last name to everything after the 1st space in the split array. `John Smith` would get split into `John` and `Smith`, and `John Smith Jr.` would get split into `John` and `Smith Jr.`. Is this possible to do in the mongo shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mongo shell to perform this one time activity

```
db.User.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { // loop over all the records
    if (doc.fullName && doc.fullName.split) {
        var name = doc.fullName.split(' ');
        if (name && name.length) {
            doc.firstName = name[0];
            if (name[1]) doc.lastName = name[1];
            // delete doc.fullName;
            db.User.save(doc); // save back the record
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what we were looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Improving a little bit on Tuchar's answer to actually put the remainder names in the last name, and also not use the deprecated `.save()`:

```js
db.User.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
  if (doc.fullName && doc.fullName.split) {
    const parts = doc.fullName.split(' ');
    db.User.updateOne({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {
      firstName: parts.shift(1),
      lastName: parts.join(' ')
    }});
  }
});
```